# Ubuntu 18.04 Hangs while working with Eclipse

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, freeze, eclipse

So, I am a newbie in Linux and recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu. Now, a few days ago, I was working on Eclipse and suddenly everything froze for about a minute and then I saw this on my screen:
[image]

I didn't understand what does it mean and then I forcefully pressed the Power Off button on my HP laptop to shut it down and then restarted it. Although it worked fine after restarting.

But can anyone tell me what does these messages mean and why did they arrive? And did I do correctly by forcefully shutting it down or should I have done something different?

Answer (score 2):

The black screen is showing boot messages when Ubuntu is restarting after it crashed. The boot message says that it is trying to recover the journal of the ext4 filesystem on the `/dev/sda2` partition that may have been damaged when Ubuntu crashed. A journaling filesystem is a filesystem that maintains a special file called a journal that is used to repair any inconsistencies that occur as the result of an improper shutdown of a computer. This protects the operating system against damage that could be caused by crashes that occasionally happen for unavoidable reasons such as electrical power interruptions.

Sometimes when Ubuntu crashes the operating system will respond to the keyboard combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>. The correct way to regain control of the computer when it crashes and all else fails is by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>SysRq</kbd> (which is the Print Screen key) while slowly typing REISUB to perform a safe reboot. One way to remember REISUB is to memorize the phrase "Reboot Even If System Utterly Broken".